# Is there a module to interface with Fabric.io or crashlytics in node.js to create an Electron app?

Tags: node.js, electron, crashlytics, fabric.io

I'm working on an Electron app and I would like to log crashes into Fabric.io or crashlytics (or an equivalent) but I can't find a Node package.

Does someone knows a such module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks. We do not currently support Electron or any node based tools.